# Low contrast wordmark in chat transcripts

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

[image]

Really minor, (maybe even intentional) but it bugs me all the same..
Thought I'd report it just in case it wasn't supposed to be like that :)

Comment: Note the same logo/background is used on the list of Blender.SE rooms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot to check and fix that part in the excitement of the launch :) The logo has a darker background now in those places.

Comment: Now it looks very weird in the chat room list page...

Answer (score 4):

I would add that this same issue is visible on the site chat page: http://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=blender.stackexchange.com (oddly none of the other chat pages are styled with the new blender site theme.)

[image: chat page with logo]

Comment: Why would they be? AFAIK only the site page is specific to blender.SE

Answer (score 2):

This also occurs in any of the B.SE chat rooms.

For example, part of the conversation with Mike Pan today: (Don't hate on Mike, he realized his mistake soon after :P)

[image]

You can barely see the "Blender Stack Exchange" next to the new logo.

Comment: LOL, a wonderful addition to our site history.